# How to set wire format on a property without changing type definition?

Tags: protobuf-net

This type is defined in an assembly where I cannot add a reference to protobuf-net:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[XmlType] // for XML or protobuf-net serialization
public struct PointI
{
    public PointI(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }

    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public int X;
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public int Y;
    ...
}
```

How can I use `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default` to specify zig-zag storage to optimize output size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(PointI), true);
metaType[1].DataFormat = metaType[2].DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.ZigZag;
```

That do ? In other news: mutable structs... bleugh...

Comment: I decided for the sake of being independent of the original source code to go with this instead: `var meta = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(PointI), false);`
`meta.Add(1, "X")[1].DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.ZigZag;`
`meta.Add(2, "Y")[2].DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.ZigZag;` The `false` parameter causes the `XmlElement` attributes, if any, to be ignored.